# Creating a new text file in a directory using org-capture

Tags: org-capture

Following this response: `Org-Mode - How do I create a new file with org-capture` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902620/org-mode-how-do-i-create-a-new-file-with-org-capture?

I am trying to make this piece of code work, but I get the error: invalid file location: nil.

```
(defun capture-report-date-file (path)
  (let ((name (read-string "Name: ")))
    (expand-file-name (format "%s-%s.txt"
                              (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d")
                              name) path)))

(setq org-capture-templates   
      '(("t"
         "todo"
         entry
         (file (capture-report-date-file  "~/path/path/name"))
         "* TODO")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is outdated. Since version 9.1 `org-capture-templates` no longer accepts S-expressions as file names, so you have to turn:

```
(capture-report-date-file  "~/path/path/name")
```

into

```
(lambda () (capture-report-date-file  "~/path/path/name"))
```

Comment: Interesting! I knew something was amiss, thanks. I tried it and get the following error:ebugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Invalid capture target specification: (lambda nil ...")
  signal(error ("Invalid capture target specification: (lambda nil ..."))
  error("Invalid capture target specification: %S" (lambda nil (capture-report-date-file "~/path/path/name")))
  (let ((target val)) (error "Invalid capture target specification: %S" target))

Comment: Do you also see this with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: It gives me this error: `org-capture-expand-file: Symbol’s value as variable is void: capture-report-date-file`. When I make the function `(interactive)`, I run `M-x capture-report-date-file`, and returns: `funcall-interactively: Wrong number of arguments: ((t) (path) (interactive) (let ((name (read-string "Name: "))) (expand-file-name (format "%s-%s.txt" (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d") name) path))), 0`. I'm clueless!

Comment: `emacs -Q` won't load your init file so you will have to paste the code above to your scratch buffer and [evaluate](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html)) both `capture-report-date-file` and `org-capture-templates` manually, usually by pressing `C-x C-e`. Once that's done press `M-x org-capture` and follow the prompt. The second error is expected.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did. I copied it into the scratch buffer and evaluated it. The error is after doing M-x org-capture and pressing the "t".

Comment: See by yourself: [screenshot video](https://imgur.com/a/xRvgqTN)

Comment: You have `(lambda () capture-report-date-file "~/Desktop")`. It should be `(lambda () (capture-report-date-file  "~/Desktop"))`.

Comment: I changed it and same thing: `org-capture-set-target-location: Invalid capture target specification: (file (lambda nil (capture-report-date-file "~/Desktop")) "* TODO")`. Have you tried yourself? Does it work on your end?

Comment: You're not wrapping the function correctly. It should be `(file (lambda () (capture-report-date-file  "~/Desktop")))`.

Comment: Damn... now I got it! It was the parenthesis. I couldn't understand "wrapping", as I am no programmer!

Comment: How about prompting fro the directory?

Comment: Perhaps `read-directory-name`.

Comment: Expand, please.